# Use Cryptolib4pascal in Delphi to duplicate Rfc2898derivebytes from C#

Tags: delphi, encryption-symmetric

I need to communicate from a Delphi application to a C# application. The C# application enforces encryption using the Rfc2898derivebytes among other things. I have got Password, Salt and the resulting bytes of the Rfc2898DeriveBytes. My implementation using CryptoLib4Pascal is shown below.
The Hasdh256 part is proven to be right towards the C# source. Any suggestions on what is wrong with the ClpGenerator part?

```
    Hash256 := THashFactory.TCrypto.CreateSHA2_256;
    Hash256Result := Hash256.ComputeString(Key, TEncoding.UTF8);
    KeyBytes := Hash256Result.GetBytes;

    SaltBytes := TConverters.ConvertStringToBytes(Salt, TEncoding.UTF8);

    ClpGenerator := TPkcs5S2ParametersGenerator.Create(TDigestUtilities.GetDigest('SHA-1'));
    ClpGenerator.Init(KeyBytes, SaltBytes, 1000);
    PBKDF2_KeyBytes := (ClpGenerator.GenerateDerivedMacParameters(48 * 8) as IKeyParameter).GetKey();

    SetLength(CryptKey, 32);
    Move(PBKDF2_KeyBytes[0], CryptKey[0], 32);
    SetLength(CryptIV, 16);
    Move(PBKDF2_KeyBytes[32], CryptIV[0], 16);
```

I have tried to change the salt encoding from UTF8 to UNICODE based on this article: https://medium.com/rabbit-mobile-business-blog/writing-c-s-rfc2898derivebytes-in-php-88fa8c096dcb